# Pass $user object to a template file

Tags: php, templates, laravel-5.3

I'm using `layouts.app` as my template file for all my views. I want to send the user to its authenticated users profile (within my dropdown in the top-right corner of my menu), like so:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="{{ url('/users/' . $users->id) }}">@lang('user.profile')</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately `$users` is undefined. How would I define `$users` without a controller?

**Solution:**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="{{ url('/users/' . auth()->user()->id) }}">@lang('user.profile')</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This looks like TWIG. Am I right? Is `$users` undefined because you haven't passed it when you called `render`, or don't you know how to get the value of `$users` from outside a controller?

Comment: Furthermore, the word `$users` is plural, which makes me think it might be an array; but you're trying to get a property from it. Is the name wrong?

Comment: @BenHillier It's actually blade. Yeah, I haven't passed anything to the blade and I don't know how exactly without a controller; that's why the `$users` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always access the Auth facade in your blade views.

```
{{ url('/users/' . Auth::user()->id) }}
```

However you should ensure that the user is actually logged in.

```
@if(Auth::user())
   ... stuff you want to show ...
@endif
```

Besides Facades you can ofcourse pass anything you want to your views / templates. Usually you do this in your controller. As an aditional quick overview:

- Your routes catches the request and either calls a controller function or responds directly

So for example:

```
// respond directly within route definition
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('home');
});
```

You have multiple options to add values here.

```
return view('home')->with(['user' => Auth::user()]);
```

or

```
$user = Auth::user();
return view('home', compact('user'));
```

or

```
return view('home', ['user' => Auth::user()]);
```

All three methods will allow you to access $user from your view. However, don't forget that Auth::user() might be null if the user is not logged in. So always check for it in an outer if clause.

Comment: What about passing in other objects to the template? I'm assuming you can't besides the `Auth` facade.

Comment: i will enhance my answer in a second

Comment: So would this work (in both route and controller): `return view('layouts.app', ['user' => Auth::user()]);`?

Comment: yes, absolutly as claimed in the official docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#passing-data-to-views - however a layout is usally used as layout and not as returned view directly.